# Ionic-v4 Keyboard covering input field in iOS 13

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ios13

I've been trying to solve this particular bug for quite a while, but I haven't made any progress in fixing it.

Anyway, the bug basically is where when clicking on an input, the keyboard will cover the input until I start inputting numbers, at which point it'll scroll down correctly.. (Also, it suddenly loses its translucency and becomes solid... I'm not sure what's causing that either...)'

I've already uninstalled ionic-plugin-keyboard, and downgrading cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard to version 2.0.5 didn't fix the issue for me (I'm currently running v2.2.0). I'm also running the latest version of cordova-plugin-ionic-webview (v4.1.2)

[Here's an imgur link showing the bug in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mj9T.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea about the problem and I know it's not a solution but, why not try to make your screen more bigger? I think that only a `.body{margin-bottom:50rem}` give to your app a chance to scroll

Comment: Try to play with `KeyboardResizeMode`, more information you can find on this page https://ionicframework.com/docs/enterprise/keyboard

Answer (score 2):

**Unstable for IOS 13**
"cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" KeyboardResize feature is unstable for IOS 13.
Issue is still open on git with no proper solution.
[View not resizing on iOS](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/issues/35)

I am using it in both Android and IOS so i had to came up with a workaround in my code(not a good one btw but works so i am putting it here).

**Step 1:** Set resizing to none in for config.xml

```
<preference name="KeyboardResize" value="false" />
```

**Step 2:** Add an empty div just above your footer with display set to none.

```
<div class="keyboardFix" style="display:none"></div>
```

**Step 3:** Now set the height of .keyboardFix class equal to keyboard height and make it visible just before keyboard using "keyboardWillShow" event.

```
  window.addEventListener("keyboardWillShow", function (evt) {
    if (rootParams.baseModel.cordovaDevice() && rootParams.baseModel.cordovaDevice() == 'IOS') {
              $(".keyboardFix").height(evt.keyboardHeight * 0.9 );
              $(".keyboardFix").css("display","block");
    }
  });
```

**Step 4:** Make is go away just before keyboard hides.

```
  window.addEventListener("keyboardWillHide", function (evt) {
    if (rootParams.baseModel.cordovaDevice() && rootParams.baseModel.cordovaDevice() == 'IOS'){
              $(".keyboardFix").height(0);
              $(".keyboardFix").css("display","none");
    }
  });
```

Note:  If condition only required if you are using same UI for cross platform i.e. Android